# localhost proxy INADDR_LOOPBACK possible?

Tags: delphi, winsock

so I have coded a simple proxy server,but I am having a few problems:
-windows defender pops up saying do you want to allow this program through your firewall.
-since I use INADDR_ANY anyone can access the proxy if the port is forwarded.

so what I want to know is can I use INADDR_LOOPBACK for the incoming connections from chrome/etc.

```
s:=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
inc(LePort);
adr.sin_family:=AF_INET;
adr.sin_port:=htons(LePort);
adr.sin_addr.S_addr:=INADDR_LOOPBACK;//possible?
Bind(S,adr,SizeOf(adr));
if winsock.Listen(S,20)<>SOCKET_ERROR then Break;
closesocket(s);
```

i've tried,but chrome says the proxy server isn't responding which leads me to believe I can't do it...i'm okay with that,but what should I do about the antivirus popup?

Comment: You called `bind`; did it succeed? You've tested with Chrome; have you tried connecting with anything else? What about when you connect with a simple telnet client?

Comment: log:
started.
sock_error - bind - port:999-wsagetlasterror:0
---
fails.
Yes,i've also tried also lightshot,which the result was success when adr.sin_addr.S_addr:=INADDR_ANY.
And what do you mean about connecting with a telnet client?

Comment: I mean connect with a telnet client. `telnet localhost`. Then type HTTP at the prompt: `GET / HTTP/1.0`; 'HOST example.com`. See how your program responds. If *that* doesn't work, then don't bother trying Chrome.

Comment: I don't understand your log. Where did it come from. In your code, you ignore the result of `bind`, so how does it appear in your log? When your log says "fails," what is it referring to? Does `bind` return 0 or `Socket_Error`? If the latter, then what does `WsaGetLastError` return?

Comment: I of course edited the source to give me that info,WsaGetLastError returns 0(no error) and what I mean by fail is I meant that it fails to listen on any of the ports(999-65535)(which most of them are not in use).
@Rob Kennedy

Comment: So `bind` succeeds but `listen` fails? Then what does `WsaGetLastError` return from *that* failure?

Comment: no no,bind fails and continues the loop which results in a failure to find a port to use.

Comment: Please copy and paste real code that demonstrates the problem and behaves the way you say it does. You refer to a loop, but there is no loop shown. You supposedly check the result of `bind`, but this code doesn't do that. I'm through guessing what you're doing.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy
http://pastebin.com/80ZtWU43
i've modified the code a little bit,but it doesn't change the problem.